# Differentiating under the integral sign problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals

Knowing that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},$$
evaluate the integral $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2y+1}\,dx.$$
for $y > 0$

Comment: Presumably you need $y>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The integral diverges if $y \le 0$. For $y\gt 0$, let $x\sqrt{y}=u$.

Comment: and then do what?

Comment: We are integrating $e\cdot e^{-x^2y}$. Let $u$ be as in post. Then $dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{y}}$. Do the substitution. We want $\int_0^\infty \frac{e}{\sqrt{y}}e^{-u^2}\,du$. This is a "constant" times an integral you have been told the value of.

Comment: but shouldn't it be $dx=du/2√y$ ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. We have $u=x\sqrt{y}$. Think of $y$ as a **constant**. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{y}$, so $du=\sqrt{y}\,dx$, or equivalently $dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{y}}$.

Comment: yes right thanks a lot my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

$$u^2=x^2y\Longrightarrow2udu=2xydx\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{u}{\frac{u}{\sqrt y}y}du=\frac{du}{\sqrt y}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2y+1}dx=\frac{e}{\sqrt y}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\frac{e}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{u}}$$